# How to add threadDealy in STM code in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, ghci, stm

The following code section has been written in `ghci`

```
 type GNum = TVar Int  
-- updateNum will read a num and add the given value to it
updateNum :: GNum -> Int -> STM ()
updateNum n v =
  do t <- readTVar n
     writeTVar n (v + t)
-- transaction read a number say n1 and replace value of n2 by n1 + v. 
-- v is a given value.
myTransaction :: GNum -> GNum -> Int -> IO ()
myTransaction n1 n2 v =
atomically $ do 
        x <- readTVar n1
        y <- readTVar n2
        let z =  ( quot x v )
        -- threadDelay (10^6 * 2)  --How to include this?
        updateNum n2 z
```

How to include **treadDelay** into this block of code?
Why I want this? Actually I wanted to force the thread T1 to wait, so that in between other thread can update the value of n1. Thus T1 will face an **inconsistency** at commit time.

When I include the line threadDelay (10^6 * 2) it show the following error:-

```
Couldn't match type 'IO' with 'STM'
exptected type: STM()
  Acutal type: IO()
In a stmt of a 'do' block: threadDelay (10^6*2)
In the second argument o f`($)`, namely
  `do { x <- readTVar n2;
        y <- readTVar n2;
----
----
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to add artificial pressure to the system for testing, then it's okay to cheat.

```
atomically $ do
    x <- readTVar n1
    y <- readTVar n2
    let z = quot x v
    return $! unsafePerformIO (threadDelay (10^6 * 2))
    updateNum n2 z
```

You can get `unsafePerformIO` from [`System.IO.Unsafe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/System-IO-Unsafe.html).

Comment: Thanks luqui. I also tried to solve this by executing a loop. In both the cases, the output has no effect of the statement **updateNum n2 z**. What I want that after certain delay transaction will execute the update statement.

Comment: It's probably better to use [unsafeIOToSTM](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.8/20140916-162/base/GHC-Conc-Sync.html#v:unsafeIOToSTM). With sharing, it's possible that the delay above may only occur once (though I'm not certain that's the case).